# What does “ leadups and outs” mean in following content?

Tags: meaning, translation

What does "leadups and outs" mean in this quote?

> The best way to approach learning how to play "Flight of the Bumblebee" is to work on memorizing bits of it at a time. A lot of the piece is essentially a main theme with **leadups and outs** of that theme, chromatically.
>
> [Steve Booke](http://www.guitarworld.com/user/168287) in [Guitar World](http://www.guitarworld.com/what-world-not-just-another-flight-bumblebee-lesson)

Comment: Andrey, you must not rely on others to find your quotations and correctly reference them.

Comment: That excerpt would perhaps have been clearer to you if it had used a bit more explicit orthography: "... *with lead-ups and -outs of that theme,* ...". That is, *leadups* and *leadouts* are dual to each other, and bookends to the theme. That is, if this is the theme: `‾‾‾‾`, then these additions are the lead-ups and lead-outs respectively: `__/‾‾‾‾\__`. You can learn more by reading [the definition of *lead-up*](http://www.onelook.com/?w=Lead-up&ls=a) (which is more common, at least in non-jargon contexts, than *lead-out*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **lead–up**
>
> noun \ˈlēˌdəp\
>
> :  s**omething that leads up to or prepares the way for something
>   else**
>
> *the race will serve as a lead-up to the classic — Sydney (Australia) Bulletin*
>
> Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary